# How to return boolean in an Array.prototype function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to maken a function to use the AND-Logicgate but it only respons an array.
I tryed useing `toString()` and `join()` but they dont work. Can anybody help me.

Here is the Code:

```js
Array.prototype.AND = function() {
  var temp = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == false) {
      temp = false;
    }
  }
  while (this.length > 0) {
    this.pop();
  }
  this[0] = temp;
}

const test = [true, true, true, false];

test.AND();

console.log(test);
```

Comment: It responds with an array because you're performing array operations on an array. What output are you expecting? (Also you're not returning anything from that function - you're updating that array in-place).

Comment: `toString` and `join` don't modify the array. They return a new value.

Comment: **YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY PROTOTYPES OF BUILT-IN OBJECTS** unless to polyfill methods from later versions of ECMAScript.

Comment: @user3840170 that was advice given out 15 years ago when libraries were trying to monkey-patch deficits in JS. So libraries like Mootools and Prototype would be battling against each other. It's ok to add to a prototype as long as you check that there's not an existing method on there. `if (!('add' in Array.prototype)) {...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if the array contains a `false`, the prototyped function `.AND` should return `false`.

Use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if the array contains a `false`.

```js
const test = [true, true, true, false];
const test2 = [true, true, true, true];
const test3 = [true, "blah!", false];

// Make sure you do not overwrite an existing method
if(typeof(Array.prototype.AND) === "undefined"){
  Array.prototype.AND = function() {
    // Make sure the array only contains booleans
    if(this.some(item => typeof(item) !== "boolean")){
      throw `error: AND must be applied on boolean array only. Got ${JSON.stringify(this)}`
    }
    return !this.some(item => item === false)
  }
}

console.log(test.AND())   // false
console.log(test2.AND())  // true
console.log(test3.AND())  // error thrown
```

Comment: To err on the side of caution I would add an `if` statement to check to see if that method exists on the prototype, as per my comment under the post.

Comment: @Andy: Agreed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In case one is allowed to use `.reduce()` this may be helpful:

```js
const logicAndGate = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a && b, true);
      
const test = [true, true, true, false];
console.log(logicAndGate(test));
console.log(logicAndGate([true, true, true, true]));
console.log(logicAndGate([false, true]));
//test.AND();
//console.log(test);
```

Another variation may be using `.every` like this:

```js
const logicAndGate = arr => arr.every(x => !!x);

console.log(logicAndGate([true, true, true, false]));
console.log(logicAndGate([true, true, true, true]));
console.log(logicAndGate([false, true]));
```